# Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I am new in php and have seen many post related to this error but still can not find the problem. I also tried with the try catch block and did not get the exception. There is no connection problem and have also tested the query in my database.

```
$host="mysql:host=".$host_name.";dbname=".$dbname; 

$ques_code=1;

$dbh = new PDO($host, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$S=$dbh->prepare("SELECT q_code FROM question_code_submission WHERE q_num = :id");

$S->bindParam(':id', $ques_code);

$temp_name=$S->execute();

$code_name=$temp_name->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$code_name=$code_name['q_code'];
```

Comment: Please consult the manual for return types of methods you are using.

Comment: Yes, will do surely ! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$host="mysql:host=".$host_name.";dbname=".$dbname;  
$ques_code=1;

$dbh = new PDO($host, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$S=$dbh->prepare("SELECT q_code FROM question_code_submission WHERE q_num = :id");  
$S->bindParam(':id', $ques_code);    
$success = $S->execute();

if(!$success){
   echo "Query failed !!";
}else{
  $result=$S->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $code_name = $result['q_code'];
  echo $code_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$S->execute()` returns true or false, so `$temp_name` is being set to a boolean value - which explains why you can't call `$temp_name->fetch()` - it's not an object.

You don't need `$temp_name` at all, simply:

```
$S->execute();

$code_name = $S->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I did not know about the return of execute(). Thank you for letting me know :)